# Why is my observable never seeing the update to my list within a kotlin android coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to build an upload application modeled off this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/#4

I'm setting a breakpoint on line 29 (where I've commented "I never reach this breakpoint. Why not?"). Why don't I reach this breakpoint when I click on the button?

`MainActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.uploadwithprogresssimple

import android.arch.lifecycle.*
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
            .get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        val scheduler: TextView = findViewById(R.id.scheduleUpload)
        val rootLayout: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout)

        scheduler.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.uploadVideo("/foobar/abc/def")
        }

        viewModel.status.observe( this, Observer {
            // I never reach this breakpoint. Why not?
            if (it != null) {
                var size = it.size
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Size of video upload: ${size}", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }
}

data class VideoAsset(private val filename: String)

class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val viewModelJob = Job()

    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

    private val _status = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<VideoAsset>>()

    val status: LiveData<ArrayList<VideoAsset>>
        get() = _status

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        uiScope.cancel()
    }

    fun uploadVideo(filename: String) {
        uiScope.launch {
            delay(1_000)
            _status.value?.add( VideoAsset( filename) )
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Schedule upload"
            android:id="@+id/scheduleUpload"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `app/build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.uploadwithprogresssimple"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

def kotlinCoroutines = "1.1.0"

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinCoroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlinCoroutines"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case breakpoint is not reached because `setValue(T)` method of `LiveData` object is not called. Calling `setValue(T)` results in the observers calling their `onChanged()` method. Try to change your code to call `setValue(T)` method, i.e.:

```
val list = _status.value ?: arrayListOf<VideoAsset>()
list.add(VideoAsset(filename))
_status.value = list
```

Note: `setValue(T)` in Kotlin is replaced with property assigning: `_status.value = list` instead of `_status.setValue(list)`

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Is there a way I could refactor my viewmodel to prevent this accidental update to the object instead of the method which goes through the correct observable chain? I wish kotlin and the interface prevented me from doing the wrong thing as I did here.

Comment: I don't see `setValue` in your sample code. Did you intend to do enter different code?

Comment: Add, it is a getter/setter and kotlin looks slightly different. Got it, thanks!

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: To motivate you to explain the difference between your suggestion and what the code said. It worked, so I accepted your answer!